# Instantiate a data.frame with list in a cell in one step

Tags: r, dataframe

If I do

```
data.frame(`Type` = list(c("aa", "bb")))
```

The list is spread in lines, and I got the output:

```
  c..aa....bb..  
1            aa  
2            bb
```

Whereas if I do it in three steps:

```
df = data.frame(`Type` = NA)
df$Type <- list(c("aa", "bb"))
df
```

Got it good:

```
    Type  
1 aa, bb
```

Also I need to instantiate `Type` first. A link to understand those behaviours is very welcome.

Comment: You don't need to instantiate Type first, why not `DF = data.frame(); DF[1, "Type"] = list(list(c("aa","ss")))`?

Comment: To be clear, I needed to instantiate Type to make it works, but I did not like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `I()`:

```
data.frame(Type = I(list(c("aa", "bb"))))
#     Type
# 1 aa, bb
str(.Last.value)
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ Type:List of 1
#   ..$ : chr  "aa" "bb"
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"
```

---

"dplyr" and "data.table" allow this directly:

```
library(dplyr)
data_frame(Type = list(c("aa", "bb")))
# Source: local data frame [1 x 1]
# 
#       Type
#      (chr)
# 1 <chr[2]>


library(data.table)
data.table(Type = list(c("aa", "bb")))
#     Type
# 1: aa,bb
```